# usb soundcard losing power

Tags: usb, audio, hub

I bought [this](http://www.flipkart.com/quantum-qhm-623-usb-sound-card/p/itmdmug2unfgezzt) USB soundcard.
I have [this](http://www.ebay.in/itm/7-Port-USB-HUB-Powered-Indian-Pin-AC-Adapter-High-Speed-for-PC-Mac-/111370607570?pt=IN_Computer_Components&hash=item19ee349bd2&_uhb=1) powered USB hub and I plugged the soundcard to the hub(the 2 usb ports in the pi are used by wifi dongle and usb hub). I changed the configs , and rebooted and the led on the soundcard lit up. amixer gave proper results.

Everything was fine except when I start playing anything using aplay, there is audio output for a few seconds and then the led goes off and it loses the device. A reboot doesn't even fix it. I have to power down and power up for the card to be detected again. What might be the problem?

Comment: What power does the USB hub provide in Amps? The card may not be receiving enough power to work.

Comment: the description on the [site](https://www.crazypi.com/USB-HUB-RASPBERRY-PI) where I bought it says 
External Powered with 2AMP rated Power Adapter

Comment: It also says `​Note : Many of the open market 7 port hubs comes with 1AMP adapters which will not be sufficient to run all connected devices to the hub. It suggested to have 2AMP adapters only.` - so it the power supply powering it may not be enough

Comment: but the adapter I have is rated 2A. At least thats what is printed on it.

Comment: Have you tested the sound card directly connected to the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's a power supply issue to the soud card. Keep in mind that for USB 2.0 the standard is 500mA (half Ampere).

The problem can come from two situations:

1. The power supply to your USB hub may not be providing enough current to the hub
2. The hub USB ports may not be able to provide enough current even if the hub power supply is more than capable

Is the sound card the only USB device connected that USB Hub?

The best is for you to have an USB hub that has individual power drivers to the downstream ports like [this one from yepkit](https://www.yepkit.com/products/ykush) that is able to provide 2A continuously to each downstream port and more than 4A per port in peaks.

Cheers

Comment: Disclaimer: I now working at Yepkit. So you may consider me biased on this subject.